# IE11 - AJAX Request getting cancelled automatically(it's intermittent and not happening always)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

Getting below exception when i try to perform ajax call.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied

SEC7120: Orgin https://[ABC].com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013

Pls. note, i will be accessing the resource from the same origin.

Comment: You need to include code for anybody to be able to assist you.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. So that we can have a test and see how to help.